# invalid element error in the fill <runtimeNamespace>

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I am getting an error in xml file while building LWC (want to use with vlocity component) in VS Code. after deployment.

Please help me to resolve this error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's just a linter error; you can report this to the VS Code Salesforce Extension Pack team if you want to on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues). It shouldn't stop deployments to your org, however. Note, however, that this parameter is unnecessary for Lightning Web Security organizations. If you have enabled LWS, please remove this attribute from your `.js-meta.xml` file. You can learn more about the entire process in this [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/omnistudio-and-custom-lightning-web-components/extend-a-standard-lookup-component-to-display-accounts-and-cases).